# Probability of exactly k out of n events occuring

Tags: probability

How does one calculate the probability of exactly `k` out of `n` events happening?  All of the input events are independent of each other.

I found [probability generating functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function) on Wikipedia, but couldn't understand their description of it.  I've never taken a course in statistics, but I understand basic probability notation.  I'm trying to implement this in C, but I can translate it to C myself once I understand what to do.  If necessary, an approximation to the precision of a C double is good enough.  I only need cases for which `k = 2` or `k = 3` and which `n = 8`, but a general solution would be nice for posterity and for me in case I realize I need more cases.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

suppose for event $j$ the probability is $p_j$ and set $q_j=1-p_j$. now form the product:
$$
P(x) = \prod_j (p_j x + q_j)
$$
so now how do you interpret $[x^k] P(x)$ (the coefficient of $x^k$ in $P(x)$?

suppose you have three independent events with probabilities $\frac12, \frac23, \frac34$ then
$$
P(x) = (\frac12 x + \frac12)(\frac23 x + \frac13)(\frac34 x+\frac14) \\
= \frac1{24}(x+1)(2x+1)(3x+1) \\
= \frac1{24}(6x^3+11x^{\color{blue}2}+6x+1)
$$
so, for example, the probability of $\color{blue} 2$ events happening is $\frac{11}{24}$

Comment: What does "the coefficient of x^k in P(x)" mean?

Comment: i have added a simple example, which may clarify the ideas for you. the power of $x$ tells you how many events occur, because a factor of $x$ is attached to each of the $p$.

Comment: Thank you!  It seems to be working.

Comment: glad to be of assistance!